this declaration has no storage class or type specifier - compiler not detecting consteval
I have a question about why I'm getting the two problems, this declaration has no storage class or type specifier, and expected a ';' ln 3 col 11, of the code: Main.cpp:
#include <iostream>

consteval int get_value(){
    return 3;
}

int main(){
    constexpr int value = get_value();
    std::cout << "value : " << value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

For some reason with this code my compiler doesn't detect consteval as a valid int.
Tasks.Json file

{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "Build with MSVC",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/std:c++20",
                "/EHsc",
                "/Fe:",
                "${fileDirname}\\rooster.exe",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: cl.exe"
        }
    ]
}

c_cppp_properties.json

{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

I'm using cl.exe to compile and run task on visual studio code. my compiler cl.exe version is Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.41.34120 for x86. Any solutions are greatly appreciated, thanks!
I've tried changing cpp standard from c++latest to c++20, because I thought that consteval wasn't being detected because c++20 wasn't a confirmed standard.
 *  Executing task: Build with MSVC 

Starting build...
cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && cl.exe /Zi /std:c++20 /EHsc /Fe: C:\Scripts\c++Scripts\The-C-20-Masterclass-Source-Code-main\The-C-20-Masterclass-Source-Code-main\02.EnvironmentSetup\1.Windows\4.V_s_CodeMsvcConfiguration\rooster.exe C:\Scripts\c++Scripts\The-C-20-Masterclass-Source-Code-main\The-C-20-Masterclass-Source-Code-main\*.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.41.34120 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

*.cpp
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:\Scripts\c++Scripts\The-C-20-Masterclass-Source-Code-main\The-C-20-Masterclass-Source-Code-main\*.cpp': No such file or directory

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it



you must have a different code, because this one compiles w/o errors: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WxPve14Gj

What compiler are you using?

The first link showed 3 compilers. gcc, clang and msvc v19 latest (which means the compiler in Visual Studio 2022). You are using a msvc version from Visual Studio 2019: "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",

You are building with C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe and not with MSVC, and not setting the -sts=c++20 to gcc. 1. The gcc path is clearly shows that you did not follow the visual studio guide. 2. Are you running Code Runner extension? 3. Run the task "Build with MSVC" instead of Code Runner.

To summarize: You claim to use MSVC 19.41.34120, but you show configuration to use an older MSVC 19.29 from 2019 and then you also show build output from a build with GCC of unknown version which clearly doesn't use the shown configuration. Something seems to have gone very wrong in your setup or way that you use it. You should explain everything you did and are doing in detailed steps.

Add vscode - or any IDE used - as tag, and remove "cl.exe".

As one commenter mentioned:

The first link showed 3 compilers. gcc, clang and msvc v19 latest (which means the compiler in Visual Studio 2022). You are using a msvc version from Visual Studio 2019: "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

The answer to the question was to change the compiler path to 2022, as suggested here, thanks!
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Change the compiler path to Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\Hostx64\x64
